# Settings of Workflow Persistence with IIS

Tags: iis, workflow-foundation, appfabric

I'm facing a problem with Workflow Persistence, I'm already removed APP Fabric and reinstall it but there is Problem in setting workflow persistence in IIS![the SQL Server store of Workflow Persistence is empty and I checked it in machine.config it exists].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the web.config files in
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config , there is difference between them, the x64 version contains more connections strings than the x32 version. you need to make them similar in connections strings.
my reference:
https://ivanfioravanti.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/appfabric-cannot-find-connection-string-for-connection-name-applicationserverworkflowinstancestoreconnectionstring/